Trying to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS
I have run update-manager and installed everything available. I get "The software on this computer is up to date." But when I try to update, it keeps saying "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." It said "mysql_client is being held back". I tried sudo apt install mysql_client, but it got a bunch of errors:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-client-8.0 but 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-client-core-8.0 but 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Thanks

Did a quick search and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78825592/i-have-problem-installing-mysql-on-ubuntu-24-04

Have you tried uninstalling it? It's quite lightweight, so you can easily reinstall it when needed. Also, I recommend using do-release-upgrade for upgrading, as the GUI upgrade tends to freeze for me every time!

How do I use do-release-upgrade? Is it part of update-manager, or apt?

I believe it's part of the ubuntu-release-upgrader package that is pre installed in most Ubuntus.

OK, I uninstalled mysql and got the upgrade started; it download a bunch of stuff, then failed, and now when I run update-manager, it freezes up and has to be killed. I'm in limbo!

Have you tried do-release-upgrade? The GUI tool almost always freezes, you can see the logs and the progress from this terminal command. Just run `sudo do-release-upgrade' in terminal.

Take a look at this.
